# FLOUR tortillas as a crust?

Tags: baking

I am making a chili cheese tater tot casserole and would like to know could I use flour tortillas on the bottom or would that be a bad idea since I am baking it at 350 for 45 minutes

Comment: Hi Joel. Welcome to Seasoned Advice! It would be helpful if you would include your entire recipe here so folks can give you an informed response. For example, if this casserole is soupy in consistency flour tortillas on the bottom might sog out and make a goopy mess. It's hard to say without details.

Comment: @Preston : they don't sog out, but they're somewhere between what you'd get with a dried lasagna noodle and a fresh lasagna noodle.  (I use them in an enchilada casserole recipe that calls for dipping each one in water before placing it in the dish ... and it's always on top of a layer of sauce)

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you absolutely can use flour tortillas on the bottom of your casserole. I disagree with @Rob's answer as I've never found the need to pre-heat the tortillas whether used as you intend, or when rolled. And I've never seen a recipe calling for that step. (Except when there is no further cooking.)

Answer (score 2):

Many casseroles and dishes use rolled up tortillas containing meat and cheese, placed in a pan, and baked in the oven. You should be able to do the same but I would be sure to pre-heat the shells just as you would with any tortilla wrapped serving.